# Build debian package of Django 1.4 for squeeze

Tags: debian, debian-squeeze, dpkg, django

I need to build a debian package for Squeeze of Django 1.4 to add to our local aptitude repository. I found a package [here](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/python-django) under `Download Source Package python-django:` [[python-django_1.4-1.debian.tar.gz]](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/python-django/python-django_1.4-1.debian.tar.gz). I'm trying to build using [these instructions](http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/maint-guide/build.en.html) but I get this error:

```
dpkg-source: error: can't build with source format '3.0 (quilt)': no orig.tar file found
dpkg-buildpackage: error: dpkg-source -b django_deb gave error exit status 255
```

Maybe this is really easy but I have no experience building debian packages. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to continue or what I should do instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone had already added Django 1.4 to the repo since after I checked last time, a few weeks ago. If someone wants to answer with any great ideas your still welcome.